# android webview with russian text formated erreur

Tags: android, webview

in my android application I have a webView but when I made this code:

```
webViewopresentation.loadData("<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /><body>    <p><span style=\"color:#FF0000\">Привет, как дела?</span></p>   </body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

it shows me this text.

> ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, ÐºÐ°Ðº Ð´ÐµÐ»Ð°?

What is the problem please?

Comment: try to write russian language using google russian input tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use it

```
webViewopresentation.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using assets, just keep your html page in asset folder with following text

```
<html> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=utf-8"> <body> <p> <span style = " color: # FF0000  "> Привет, как дела </ span> </ p> </ body> </ html>
```

and then load that html page in your webview (view)

```
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/newhtml.html");
```